# Multiple checkbox in Flutter from Json

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been able to display json data from API in FutureBuilder Widget. However, the widget has checkbox for each list. Whenever I check on one list, the whole list get checked.

I want a help on how to check each list individually and be able to use the data of the selected list.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Location extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationState createState() => _LocationState();
}

class _LocationState extends State<Location> {
  //initState
  bool selected = false;

  Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cdjVKlMEde?indent=2");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<User> users = [];

    for (var u in jsonData) {
      User user =
          User(u["index"], u["about"], u["name"], u["email"], u["picture"]);

      users.add(user);
    }

    print(users.length);

    return users;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select City'),
      ),
         body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getUsers(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage:
                          NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].picture),
                    ),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
                    trailing: Checkbox(
                        value: selected,
                        onChanged: (bool val) {
                          setState(() {
                            selected = val;
                          });
                        }),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  DetailPage(snapshot.data[index])));
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;

  DetailPage(this.user);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(user.name),
    ));
  }
}

class User {
  final int index;
  final String about;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String picture;

  User(this.index, this.about, this.name, this.email, this.picture);
}
```

I want a help on how to check each list individually and be able to use the data of the selected list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue, please try to run the below code.

**Explanation**

- Initialize a bool type list

  **var userStatus = List();**
- Add bool value false to the list at the time of adding user as shown in below code

  **userStatus.add(false)**
- Now set a value at the checkbox

  **value: userStatus[index]**
- In onChanged event of checkbox, toggle the user status by using set state

  **userStatus[index] = !userStatus[index];**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Location(),
    );
  }
}


class Location extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationState createState() => _LocationState();
}

class _LocationState extends State<Location> {
  //initState
  bool selected = false;
  var userStatus = List<bool>();

  Future<List<User>> _getUsers() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cdjVKlMEde?indent=2");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<User> users = [];

    for (var u in jsonData) {
      User user =
      User(u["index"], u["about"], u["name"], u["email"], u["picture"]);

      users.add(user);
      userStatus.add(false);
    }

    print(users.length);

    return users;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Select City'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getUsers(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].picture),
                    ),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].name),
                    subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index].email),
                    trailing: Checkbox(
                        value: userStatus[index],
                        onChanged: (bool val) {
                          setState(() {
                            userStatus[index] = !userStatus[index];
                          });
                        }),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  DetailPage(snapshot.data[index])));
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;

  DetailPage(this.user);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(user.name),
        ));
  }
}

class User {
  final int index;
  final String about;
  final String name;
  final String email;
  final String picture;

  User(this.index, this.about, this.name, this.email, this.picture);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Pls how do I make the selection persist even when the app is restarted and how to parse the data in another screen?

Comment: Use shared preference , it will provide a persistent store for simple data.

Comment: If you didn't found any solution, i will give you detailed explanation.